# Which operator i should call?

Tags: c++

I have a little problem with operators in c++.
I have following code:

```
class Segment{ 
public: 
double a, b;
Segment(double A=0, double B=0) : a(A), b(B) {}
// Segment operator&(const Segment & d){
//                 Segment ss;
//                 if (d >= this.a && d<this.b)
//                 {
//                         return 1;
//                 }
//                 else{
//                         return 0;
//                 }         
//         }
};
int main (){

//Segment seg2(2,5);
Segment seg(2,3), s = 2*((seg-2)/2+seg)/3+1;
            pokaz(s);
            cout << (s(5) ? "true" : "false") << endl;
}
```

I would like to call operator using s(5) which return me true if 5 is between 2 and 5 and false if not... but i dont know how to call properly this kind of operator..
I know it's maybe a noob question but i learning about operators and i need a little help..
So could anybody help me and show how to correctly call this operator? I fight with this about 3 hours with no effects :(

Comment: You'll have to uncomment the code to be able to call it.

Comment: If you are trying to overload the conditional (ternary) operator, well, you can't.

Comment: There are many, MANY things wrong with this code. 1: You're trying to overload the ``&`` operator, and it seems to do something that is not the equivalent of a bitwise ``and``, which is not what people are going to expect. 2: You don't actually USE the ``&`` operator in your code. 3: Inside your ``&`` operator overload, you use the ``>=`` and ``<`` on a ``Segment`` compared to a ``double``, but you have not overloaded those operators for those inputs (or at all, for that matter). You also later use the ``*`` , ``-`` ``\`` and ``+`` operators on a ``Segment`` again without overloading them.

Comment: Ask about the problem not the step. What are you actually trying to do? Currently it is not very clear why you even need an operator overload, which operator you wish to overload, or what behavior you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks for help! I made it: 
It works bool operator()(double d)
        {
                if (d >=(this->a) && d<(this->b))
                return true;
        else
                return false;             
        }

Comment: @Blackchart Sure, that would work, but isn't all all what your code reflects doing.

Answer (score 2):

You have the following code:

```
s = 2*((seg-2)/2+seg)/3+1
```

`seg-2` requires an `operator-()` between `Segment` and `int`.

Depending on what that function returns, `(seg-2)/2` may require an `operator/()` function between the returned value type and `int`.

Depending on what type `(seg-2)/2` evaluates to, `(seg-2)/2+seg)` may require an `operator+()` function between that type and `Segment`.

Depending on what type `(seg-2)/2+seg` evaluates to, `2*((seg-2)/2+seg)` may require an `operator*()` between `int` and the type `(seg-2)/2+seg` evaluates to.

Depending on that type `2*((seg-2)/2+seg)` evaluates to, `2*((seg-2)/2+seg)/3` may require an `operator/()` between that type and `int`.

Depending on that type `2*((seg-2)/2+seg)/3` evaluates to, `2*((seg-2)/2+seg)/3+1` may require an `operator+()` between that type and `int`.

Hopefully, that evaluates to `Segment`. Otherwise, you will have to define a way to convert that type to `Segment` to be able to use:

```
s = 2*((seg-2)/2+seg)/3+1
```

If you provide `operator+()`, `operator-()`, `operator*()` `and operator/()` between `Segment`s, you'll be all set since you have a way to construct a `Segment` from `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding a few nasty details in your code, I think you are looking for something like that:

```
template<typename T=double>
class Segment{
public:
    T a, b;
    Segment(const T& A=T{}, const T& B=T{}) : a(A), b(B) {}
    bool operator()(const T& d) { return d >= a && d < b; }
};

int main() {
    Segment<> seg{3,7};
    for (int x=0; x < 10; ++x)
        std::cout << seg(x) << " ";  // 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

No?

Of course, you need some additional numerical operators between a `Segment` and a number for expression `2*((seg-2)/2+seg)/3+1` to work. For instance,

```
template<typename T=double>
class Segment{
public:
    T a, b;
    Segment(const T& A=T{}, const T& B=T{}) : a(A), b(B) {}
    bool operator()(const T& d){ return d >= a && d < b; }
    template<typename X>
    Segment operator+(const X& x) { return {a+x, b+x}; }
};

int main() {
    Segment<> s{3,7}, seg = s+2;
    for (int x=0; x < 10; ++x)
        std::cout << seg(x) << " ";  // 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

But it takes more work so that all combinations work correctly.